# Want to Pass Custom Date for DataAnnotation Property MinimumDate

Tags: c#, maui, syncfusion

I am working on C# MAUI App with Syncfusion UI controls (VS 2022 .NET 8.0) & MVVM,

For one of my Field in Model Class I want to set MinimumDate String value to 18 years ago from Today (a adult person).

```
using Syncfusion.Maui.DataForm;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Padmavati
{
    class tempClass1
    {
        private string minDt = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18).ToShortDateString();
        private const string minAgeDt = minDt;  //error here CS0236

        [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DataFormDateRange(DisplayFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy", MinimumDate = minAgeDt)]  //error here CS0182
        public string? DOB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can't fix it like
[DataFormDateRange(DisplayFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy", MinimumDate = "2006/02/14")]

Comment: Constants have to be known at compile time. They cannot be set with a value calculated at run time. What you're trying to do is not possible with an attribute.

Comment: And it’s generally a horrible idea to store a date value as a string

Comment: if not possible with attribute then is there any other work around?

Jason - I am storing Date Value to string because the DataAnnotation Property MinimumDate accepts String Only